# Removing information about deleted volume

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

In order to increase space in my c drive, I had to delete all my volumes and create again allocating more space to C which I did, after which my drive name G didn't exist. Before this I used to install all my softwares in G. Now since the drive does not exist, I want to remove all info about the softwares I installed in G as they got deleted when volume got deleted.

I also want to install cilk++ but it gives me an error-invalid drive g:.

If I insert pendrives so I get a volume named G, cilk++ installer runs but says that it will be integrated to visual studio 2008 which i previously had in G drive(but no longer exists) and doesn't show visual studio 2010 which i recently installed in C drive. How do I fix this? Please help.

Comment: Hm.. I would run `regedit.exe` export all of `HKLM\Software` and `HKCU\Software`. Then replace every occurance of G:. Then import back. And delete keys for g: also in `HKLM\System\MountedDevices\`. Keeping all backed up is essential!

Answer (score 1):

I've got another (unstable) option.
You can use Subst (through CLI) to create a virtual drive (with the letter G of course) that would point to wherever you need.
If the folder structure is needed to be reconstruct you can use MKLink (or Sysinternals Junction) to create symlinks to folders.
The one big advantage here is that, as far as I can see, there are no any bad consequences you can't reverse easily (by undoing the virtual drive).

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing why installing program files in the designated program files directory is not just a symantical issue. Non-portable programs are referenced all throughout the system and usually break when subjected to simple file operations, or in this case, to the disappearence of the entire drive. In theory, the program files entry could be altered, but a lot of software is not build to survive this. The only viable way to move installed programs to a new drive is to uninstall them properly, then reinstall them elsewhere.

Needless to say, reformatting the drive is not equivalent to a proper uninstall procedure and with the program files missing altogether, chances of a clean and succesful uninstall are abysmal. If possible, your best bet would be to recreate the original G:-drive from backups and to remove the installed software appropriately.

Option two is to manually remove all of the remaining references to programs that were once installed on the G:-drive. A tedious task for a single program that could have left its mark in dozens of registry keys, user-space files, dependencies, third party software... For many programs, as probable in this case, this is impossible. At best, it can serve as a quick and dirty solution to patch specific problems such as the install errors for cilk++. Be prepared to continue to work with a very unstable system.

The most rigorous, but quite likely fastest and best way to resolve the situation is to backup all valuable data, format the C:-drive and reinstall the operating system and other installed software.